# How to select a query with multiple columns and put it into variables using Entity Framework and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Well, i used the entity framework model to connect my application to my database, and generated the controller and views for CRUD operations.

But now, i need to execute this query:

```
select preco_hora, hora_adicional
from dbo.Precos
where dt_ini_vgcia <= '05/08/2016'
and   dt_fim_vgcia >= '05/08/2016'
```

and put the return of these two columns (preco_hora and hora_adicional) into a variable (or a object, anything that i can manage).

So, i'm having some trouble to this simple thing ... can't get the code to work. It compile, but doesn't work.

I tried something like that:

```
//get the context of the table from the database
private EstacionamentoContext db = new EstacionamentoContext();

string hentrada = "05/08/2016";

        var results = db.Precos.SqlQuery(
            "select preco_hora, hora_adicional " +
            "from db.Precos " +
            "where dt_ini_vgcia <= @p0 " +
            "and dt_fim_vgcia >= @p0", hentrada
            );
    return Content("Resultado: = {0}", results.ToString());
```

but i'm not getting any value on the "results" variable. I tried to debug to see if the "results" get some value but i got an error when i tried to see inside the variable.

So, how can i solve this ? how can i make a object (or variable) that can receive this return ?

EDIT WITH THE SOLUTION:

The code was changed and LINQ was used to get better code. Thanks for @Jaya and @Jeric Cruz for all the help with the code.

The final code was this:

```
var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016");

            var results = db.Precos.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada
            && p.dt_fim_vgcia >= hentrada).Select(p => new { p.preco_hora, p.hora_adicional }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (results == null)
            {
                return Content("Não há preço registrado para este período de vigência");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content(String.Format("Preço por Hora = {0} e Hora Adicional = {1}", results.preco_hora.ToString(), results.hora_adicional.ToString()));
            }
```

Comment: check the hora adicional. do you need to put underscore there. hora_adicional?

Comment: `"select preco_hora, hora adicional " +`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your selected columns in your query. I think you missed the underscore.

> `preco_hora, hora_adicional`

You can try to add new `SqlParameters` when inserting your parameter value in your `SqlQuery`

> new SqlParameter("@p1", hentrada)

```
var results = db.Precos.SqlQuery(
            "select preco_hora, hora_adicional " +
            "from db.Precos " +
            "where dt_ini_vgcia <= @p1 " +
            "and dt_fim_vgcia >= @p1", new SqlParameter("@p1", hentrada)
            );
```

Refer to the link [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) for more details about SqlQuery.

And also, this query will result to a multiple value based on your columns.

=======UPDATED======
based on @Jaya's answer,  just modified the linq statement:

> First: is to parse the date string value and assigned to variable to avoid linq exception since `DateTime.Parse` is not a part of code of `linq`.

```
var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016");
```

> Second: Assigned the variable in your linq statement.

```
var results = db.Precos.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia >= hentrada && p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada);
```

> Third: is to do `Select` with `new` and not put it to string.

```
.Select(p => new {p.preco_hora, p.hora_adicional});
```

so out come will be:

```
var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016");
var results = db.Precos
.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia >= hentrada && p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada)
.Select(p => new { p.preco_hora, p.hora_adicional });
```

Comment: Indeed.

i changed the code to this:      
`var results = db.Precos.SqlQuery(
                "select preco_hora, hora_adicional " +
                "from dbo.Precos " +
                "where dt_ini_vgcia <= @p0 " +
                "and dt_fim_vgcia >= @p0", hentrada
                ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            decimal horaadd = results.hora_adicional;
            decimal preco_h = results.preco_hora;

            return Content("Hora Adicional = {0} e Preço por hora = {1}", 
    horaadd.ToString(), preco_h.ToString());
`

But now i'm getting an exception

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: i changed the code again to the LINQ example that they gave me above, but i need to know how to return or move the content inside the results variable.

Comment: you can add a "Break Point" after getting the result of `LINQ` then you can know what's inside of the `results` variable.

Comment: i'm getting this exception...
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I think it's because the field is Date and not DateTime...
There is a substitute class ?

Comment: is `dt_fim_vgcia` and `dt_fim_vgcia` are in a datetime data type?

Comment: you can immediately parse your date string to this `var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016");' then in your `linq` `var results = db.Precos.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia >= 
       hentrada 
        && p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada);`

Comment: Tried. Now i'm getting this Exception:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: replace `.Select(p => $"{p.preco_hora} {p.hora_adicional}"); ` to `.Select(p => new {p.preco_hora, p.hora_adicional});`

Comment: Man, it worked. Thank you very much for your help !! Thank you for @Jaya too who helped a lot with the first code sample.

If the query return Null it'll get an exception when you try to use the field, so it's necessary to make an IF to check if the return is Null.

I could return the Content with this line:
`return Content(String.Format("Preço por Hora = {0} e Hora Adicional = {1}", results.preco_hora.ToString(), results.hora_adicional.ToString()));`

Comment: i did. but i marked this as the main answer because it was updated.

I upvoted all responses on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things that are noticeable in your code are:

**Query**

1. Check your query that has `select preco_hora, hora adicional` -> check if the column name `hora adicional` has a space in it or does it look like `hora_adicional`

**Return statement**

2. `return Content("Resultado: = {0}", results.ToString());` ->  `results.ToString()` this would return something like `IQueryable<T>` and not the intended result.

**Suggestions**

you could try something with `LINQ` to SQL to avoid free flowing text and the ease of using EF here

```
 using System.Linq; //namespace

 var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016"); // do the parsing here and not in LINQ query.

 var results = db.Precos.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia >=  hentrada
               && p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada)
              .Select(p => $"{p.preco_hora} {p.hora_adicional}"); 
// assuming dataType of `dt_ini_vgcia` is DateTime
```

*Note: The type of results here is a collection of string and not just one. If you are expecting only one result then use `SingleOrDefault`*

Comment: Yup, we got the same opinion. Try this suggestion @LucasBarreto to use `LINQ`

Comment: how can i manage the fields preco_hora and hora_adicional inside the results variable with this code ?

Can i just return Content (result); ?

Comment: how many rows are you expecting? if its just one then you should do `results.SingleOrDefault()` or just after the select statement `.Select(p => $"{p.preco_hora} {p.hora_adicional}").SingleOrDefault()` but if you are not sure then use `FirstOrDefault()` because if more than one row is returned then `SingleOrDefault` would thrown an error. I suggest you to try this code, debug to understand better.

Comment: It can return more than 1 row, but i will only use the first row returned. I'll insert a validation logic to not let the user insert records that make this query return more than 1 row later, so, i intend to make this query return just 1 row.

But what i want to do is how to use the field INSIDE the results variable. I can use something like results.preco_hora and results.hora_adicional ?


Ah, and the dataType is Date.

Comment: i'm getting this exception...
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I think that's because the dataType is Date, not DateTime... there is a substitute method ?

Comment: Using his suggestion, you can immediately parse your date string to this `var hentrada = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2016");' then in your `linq` `var results = db.Precos.Where(p => p.dt_ini_vgcia >= 
       hentrada 
        && p.dt_ini_vgcia <= hentrada);`

Comment: with this code i'm getting this exception:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Oh sure. will modify the query.  My bad. EF cannot translate DateTime.Parse to SQL in the background

Answer (score 0):

The problem is logical, you need to read more about data connections and binding. Using parameter to declare your variables like (@p1). Examples are the best explanatory.
Try Using this method:

```
     //Connections methods vary use whatever you like 
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your_String_Name"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.open();
    string hentrada = "05/08/2016";
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT preco_hora, hora_adicional FROM db.Precos where 
    dt_ini_vgcia <= @p1 AND dt_fim_vgcia >= @p2";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", hentrada);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", somthingelse);

//to view the results of select query 
 DataSet exampledataset = new DataSet(); //data set to hold the data
 SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); // will put the results from cmd inside an adaprter.
 adapt.Fill(exampledataset); // data moved from adapter to data set 
 Gridview1.DataSource = exampledataset; //you can use gridview to present the data or any other tool.
 Gridview1.DataBind();

 conn.Close();
```

This is but one of many ways to query using C#. I encourage you to read more about [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx). Not that this is not best practice. Good practice will be using more secure method like Stored Procedure [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx).

Not: forgive my short coming English is not my first language.

Comment: the person who posted this question has a question specific to EF and if possible you should answer the same within the same bounds and not otherwise